# Vector Tile Service VS. Feature Service

Tags: web-mapping, vector-tiles, feature-layer

I've been watching the following Esri video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULhrWCIH0SQ

And the following two slides confuse me:
[image: features]
[image: vector]

What is the difference between Features and Vectors?
It seems that in both I specify the area which I want to render, and get in return data from which I can draw the point/line/polygon on the client side.

Comment: 'Vector Tiles' (square packets of data) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_tiles#:~:text=Vector%20tiles%2C%20tiled%20vectors%20or,tiles%20with%20vector%20map%20data.

Comment: With vector tiles, you cant click points/lines/polygons and get attributes returned via popups. Feature Services support this. Feature services also allow editing of data via the web map while vector tiles are static..I think...

Comment: a map service can serve vector tiles,

Answer (score 2):

Feature return vector feature, it's like regular connecting to a database or datasource but over the web.

Vector (or as in the slide and more accuratly "Vector Tile Service") return a vector tile ie. a container where all vectorial data are cropped by the tile extend and are packaged together.

You will use the tile with a style-sheet for rendering, as the rendering is client side you could use different style-sheet with the same tile set to get the symbology that suit you the most

As a single feature may be separated between several tile this format is good for base map as you get all relevant data in vectorial format in a single tile but not so for analysis.